# R friendly way to convert lots of R data frame columns to lots of vectors

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I looked at this solution: [R-friendly way to convert R data.frame column to a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070173/r-friendly-way-to-convert-r-data-frame-column-to-a-vector)

but each solution seems to involve manually declaring the name of the vector being created.

I have a large dataframe with about 224 column names. I would like to break up the data frame and turn it into 224 different vectors which preserve their label without typing them all manually. Is there a way to step through the columns in the data frame and produce a vector which has the same name as the column or am I dreaming?

Comment: Why do you think it's necessary to do that. Can't a `with()` statement help you? It would help if you provided some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) showing exactly what you want. Maybe you're looking for `list2env`? But there are usually more R-like ways to do things.

Comment: Now all we need is an `eval(parse(text=...))` answer to complete the trifecta of R's most dangerous commands.

Comment: I'm thoroughly enjoying the three "bad" ideas suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's a bad idea but this would work (using mtcars data set):

```
list2env(mtcars, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate you giving me tools of my own demise. I understand why one would be worried.

Answer (score 3):

`attach` is another dangerous command that people use to be able to access the columns of a data frame directly with their names. If you don't know why it's dangerous, though, don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another bad idea:

```
for(i in names(mtcars)) assign(i, mtcars[,i])
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for Richard:

```
for (x in names(mtcars))
    eval(parse(text=paste(x, '<- c(', paste(mtcars[[x]], collapse=',') ,')')))
```

Comment: This just screams elegance.

Comment: Well, it screams something.