# Storing the values of a column of a data.frame after removing the name in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, data-science

I want to store the values of a  column of a data.frame after removing the name in a vector. I tried the following code, but it did not work. It shows me that the type of 'my_vector' is data.frame. I would like to know why the type is data.frame and how to do it. Here is my code:

```
my_vector <- as.vector(unname(my_data.frame[column]))
```

Comment: Why not `my_data.frame$column` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070173/convert-data-frame-column-to-a-vector

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this in R is `my_vector <- my_data.frame[[column]]`