# Convert two column from dataframe to a vector R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I get this dataframe :

```
head(data)
  Cal    Cre
1 ca     h1  
2 cb     h2 
3 ca     h3
```

I try to get a vector like this:

```
foo=c("ca"="h1","cb"="h2","ca"="h3")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert data.frame column to a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070173/convert-data-frame-column-to-a-vector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    pull(Cre, name = Cal)
```